# Why it says the contract should be abstract?

Tags: solidity

Why it says the contract should be abstract?

[image]

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract YourContract is Ownable, ERC20 {
    ERC20 private token;

    //address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        //owner = msg.sender;
        // what should we do on deploy?
    }

    struct LockedAccount {
        uint256 amountETH;
        uint256 amountTokens;
        uint256 date;
    }

    mapping(address => LockedAccount) lockedAccounts;

    function approveToken(
        ERC20 _token,
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount
    ) public {
        token = _token;
        token.approve(_to, _amount);
    }

    function lockMoney(uint256 _amountTokens) public payable {
        LockedAccount memory _lockedAccounts = LockedAccount({
            amountETH: msg.value,
            amountTokens: _amountTokens,
            date: block.timestamp
        });
        lockedAccounts[msg.sender] = _lockedAccounts;
    }

    // to support receiving ETH by default
    receive() external payable {}

    fallback() external payable {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because your contract is using the ERC20 Contract (not the interface) and it requires some input in the constructor

```
    constructor() ERC20("<your-token-name>", "<your-token-symbol>") {
        //owner = msg.sender;
        // what should we do on deploy?
    }
```

As `scorpion9979` mentioned, there are probably other weird thing in the contract like `ERC20 private token;`. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you probably want to use IERC20 (the interface) otherwise your contract is ERC20 Token. Anyway those are not related to your main question

Comment: This. Plus, there are many other issues I've noticed with the contract. Apparently, it is defined as an ERC20, but still uses an ERC20 as a storage variable. The storage variable is not needed.